# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child for simple slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to right a very very rudimentary photo slider in my Rails 4 application.

I am currently putting this block of code in the scope of a `jQuery(document).ready();` function:

```
 var total_photos = $("#slides > img").length;
  console.log("photo number: "+ total_photos);
   var curren_photo = 1;

  function changePhotoInSlide(){
    if (curren_photo == total_photos){
      curren_photo=1;
    }
    console.log("in photo slidin!");
    //make current photo display none
    $('#slides:nth-child(curren_photo)').css("display", "none");
    curren_photo = curren_photo + 1;
    $('#slides:nth-child(curren_photo)').css("display", "block");
}

setInterval(changePhotoInSlide(), 4000);
```

And here is the default Document structure i am using

HTML/HAML

```
#slides
  %img{:src => "http://d1y0gk5faskefl.cloudfront.net/boston/1.jpg", :height=> 200}/
  %img{:src => "http://d1y0gk5faskefl.cloudfront.net/boston/2.jpg", :height=> 200}/
  %img{:src => "http://d1y0gk5faskefl.cloudfront.net/boston/3.jpg", :height=> 200}/
  %img{:src => "http://d1y0gk5faskefl.cloudfront.net/boston/4.jpg", :height=> 200}/
  %img{:src => "http://d1y0gk5faskefl.cloudfront.net/boston/5.jpg", :height=> 200}/
  %img{:src => "http://d1y0gk5faskefl.cloudfront.net/boston/6.jpg", :height=>200}/
  %img{:src => "http://d1y0gk5faskefl.cloudfront.net/boston/7.jpg", :height=>200}/
  %img{:src => "http://d1y0gk5faskefl.cloudfront.net/boston/8.jpg", :height=>200}/
```

CSS

```
#slides img {
  display:none;
}
#slides img{

  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:100px
}
```

I am not really sure what is going wrong, i appreciate any strategies to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You should access nth child as follows,

```
$('#slides:nth-child(' + curren_photo + ')').css("display", "none");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have concatenation problem with `curren_photo` variable.

Change

```
$('#slides:nth-child(curren_photo)').css("display", "none");
curren_photo = curren_photo + 1;
$('#slides:nth-child(curren_photo)').css("display", "block");
```

To

```
$('#slides:nth-child('+ curren_photo +')').css("display", "none");
curren_photo = curren_photo + 1;
$('#slides:nth-child('+ curren_photo +')').css("display", "block");
```